# Как сделать расширение кликер?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы автоматически нажималась кнопка формата "button class"
У меня расширение на JS. Попробовал несколько способов из интернета, но они не помогли. Может делаю что-то не так. Я совсем новичок в программировании.

Comment: Добавьте ваши попытки.

Comment: Раз способы из интернета не помогли - значит, вместо того чтобы снова идти за новой их порцией, стоит попробовать способ **не** из интернета (то есть, изучить что требуется, и написать самостоятельно. Это гарантированно поможет).

Comment: Можно такой вариант  испробовать....  Правой рукой копируешь код и вставляешь, а левой чешешь левое ухо....  и при этом рекомендуется три раза присесть....  Должно сработать....